# How to make sure lerp has ended before disabling collider2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am running a number of coroutines that move objects from one position to another every few seconds. At a certain point, I would like to disable their colliders. How can I make sure that each game object has finished 'lerping' to new position before I disable it's collider, to prevent disabling colliders in the process of a leap? Below is the relevant code:

```
    IEnumerator moveObjToRight  (Transform fromPosition, Vector3 toPosition, float duration, int newIndex)  {


            while (freePositions.Contains(objPositions[newIndex])) {

            freePositions.Add (objPositions [newIndex - 1]);
            filledPositions.Remove (objPositions [newIndex - 1]);

            float counter = 0;

        Transform startTrans = fromPosition;

        freePositions.Remove (objPositions [newIndex]);
        filledPositions.Add (objPositions [newIndex]);

            while (counter < duration) {                
                counter += Time.deltaTime;
                fromPosition.position = Vector3.Lerp (startTrans.position, toPosition, counter / duration);
                yield return null;

            }


            if (newIndex < objPositions.Count) {

                newIndex++;

                if ((newIndex == 9) || !freePositions.Contains (objPositions [newIndex]))   {

                isMovingLeft = true;

                yield return new WaitForSeconds (2.0f);

                if (freePositions.Contains (objPositions [newIndex - 2])) {

                toPosition = new Vector3(objPositions[newIndex - 2], startTrans.position.y, startTrans.position.z );
                yield return StartCoroutine(moveObjToLeft(startTrans, toPosition, 1.0f, newIndex - 2));

                }

                else if (!freePositions.Contains (objPositions [newIndex - 2])) {
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds (3.0f);

                    toPosition = new Vector3(objPositions[newIndex - 2], startTrans.position.y, startTrans.position.z );
                    yield return StartCoroutine(moveObjToLeft(startTrans, toPosition, 1.0f, newIndex - 2));


                }
            }
        }

        startTrans.position = toPosition;
        toPosition = new Vector3 (objPositions [newIndex], startTrans.position.y, startTrans.position.z);

        int waitTime = Random.Range (3, 5);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);

    }
}
```

Comment: Without providing the lerp code, how can we know when your object is done lerping? You are not new here and you know without code you wont get reasonable  help.

Comment: @Programmer I just edited the question :)

Comment: The Object is done moving after the `while loop block has finished running. `while (counter < duration) {...}` then you can disable after that. Am I missing anything?

Comment: thanks, that solves it

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerator LerpWithCompletionAction(Action onCompletion){
    while(Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, this.target.position)<0.001f)       
    {
          // Lerp
          yield return null
    }
    if(onCompletion != null) { onCompletion(); }
}
```

The check uses the distance as you cannot really rely on checking for float comparison. You could lower the check value or increase whether it happens too soon or is not happening for being too small.

Then you call like this:

```
void DisableColliders(){  // Disable your colliders }

void AnyMethod()
{
    StartCoroutine(LerpWithCompletionAction(DisableColliders));
}
```